# C# Insert into ODBC Sybase from datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, odbc, sybase

How to insert in Sybase SQL?

My code:

```
    {
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO gamyba1z (ID_GAMYBA, PRE_KOD, PRE_KODN, SAN_KOD, PRE_SKA, NL_KOD, OBJ_KOD, OB3_KOD, OB2_KOD, OB4_KOD, PRE_SK1) VALUES (@ID_GAMYBA, @PRE_KOD, @PRE_KODN, @SAN_KOD, @PRE_SKA, @NL_KOD, @OBJ_KOD, @OB3_KOD,  @OB2_KOD, @OB4_KOD,  @PRE_SK1)", conn);
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Plan_prekes VALUES(@Nr, @Data, @ID, @Pavadinimas, @S1, @S2, @S3, @S4, @Kiekis, @Darbuotojas, @Papildymas, @Akcija, @Grupe, @Klientas)", con);
        OdbcParameter ID_GAMYBA = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_GAMYBA", OdbcType.Int);
        OdbcParameter PRE_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRE_KOD", OdbcType.Char);                
        OdbcParameter PRE_KODN = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRE_KODN", OdbcType.Int);
        OdbcParameter SAN_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("@SAN_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
        OdbcParameter PRE_SKA = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRE_SKA", OdbcType.BigInt);

        OdbcParameter NL_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("@NL_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
        OdbcParameter OBJ_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("@OBJ_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
        OdbcParameter OB3_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("@OB3_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
        //OdbcParameter OB6_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("OB6_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
        OdbcParameter OB2_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("@OB2_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
        OdbcParameter OB4_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("@OB4_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
        //OdbcParameter OB5_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("OB5_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
        OdbcParameter PRE_SK1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRE_SK1", OdbcType.BigInt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows.Count; i++)
        {               
            if (dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == null)
            { 
                //Нет Id 
                MessageBox.Show("Importuota !");
                continue;
            }
            else
            { ID_GAMYBA.Value = dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value; } //ID 
            if (dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == null)
            { PRE_KOD.Value = DBNull.Value; }
            else
            { PRE_KOD.Value = dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value; } //Kod
            //if (dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == null)
            //{ PRE_KODN.Value = DBNull.Value; }
            //else
            //{ PRE_KODN.Value = dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value; }  //Data 
            if (dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value != null)
            { SAN_KOD.Value = DBNull.Value;  }
            else
            {  SAN_KOD.Value = dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;  } //Sklad
            if (dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == null)
            { PRE_SKA.Value =  DBNull.Value; }
            else
            { PRE_SKA.Value = dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value; }  //Kolicestvo

            if (dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value == null)
            { OBJ_KOD.Value = DBNull.Value; }
            else
            { OBJ_KOD.Value = dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value; } //Serija

            { PRE_KODN.Value = '1'; }                   
            { NL_KOD.Value = '0'; }
            { OB3_KOD.Value = DBNull.Value; }                    
            { OB2_KOD.Value = DBNull.Value; }
            { OB4_KOD.Value = DBNull.Value; }
            //{ OBJ_KOD.Value = DBNull.Value; }
            { PRE_SK1.Value = '0'; }
```

Error write ID_GAMYBA column in SYBASE not found.

If insert from query:

```
INSERT INTO gamyba1z (ID_GAMYBA, PRE_KOD, PRE_KODN, SAN_KOD, PRE_SKA, NL_KOD, OBJ_KOD, OB3_KOD, OB2_KOD, OB4_KOD, PRE_SK1) VALUES(14580,10010000,1, 'INGRED. T', 100,0,'','','','',0)
```

then row inserted.

Help Please, how to insert all datagridview table ???

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the exception that occurs.

Comment: Are you **100% sure** that the connection is pointing to the **exact same database** as the one where you ran the query successfully?

Comment: this connection is good. my connectionstring:OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection (@"Driver={SQL Anywhere 10};ENG=sv;UID=dba;PWD=sql;DBN=sv_eur;LINKS=TCPIP(HOST=192.168.0.75)");

Answer (score 0):

from [Microsoft ovverview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) i edit my code:

```
private void btn_insert_zaliavos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
try
        {                
            conn.Open();
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO gamyba1z (ID_GAMYBA, PRE_KOD, PRE_KODN, SAN_KOD, PRE_SKA, NL_KOD, OBJ_KOD, OB3_KOD, OB2_KOD, OB4_KOD, PRE_SK1) VALUES (?, ?, ?, '?', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn);//@ID_GAMYBA, @PRE_KOD, @PRE_KODN, @SAN_KOD, @PRE_SKA, @NL_KOD, @OBJ_KOD, @OB3_KOD,  @OB2_KOD, @OB4_KOD,  @PRE_SK1)", conn);
            OdbcParameter ID_GAMYBA = cmd.Parameters.Add("ID_GAMYBA", OdbcType.Int);
            OdbcParameter PRE_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("PRE_KOD", OdbcType.Char);                
            OdbcParameter PRE_KODN = cmd.Parameters.Add("PRE_KODN", OdbcType.Int);
            OdbcParameter SAN_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("SAN_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
            OdbcParameter PRE_SKA = cmd.Parameters.Add("PRE_SKA", OdbcType.BigInt);               
            OdbcParameter NL_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("NL_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
            OdbcParameter OBJ_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("OBJ_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
            OdbcParameter OB3_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("OB3_KOD", OdbcType.Char);                
            OdbcParameter OB2_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("OB2_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
            OdbcParameter OB4_KOD = cmd.Parameters.Add("OB4_KOD", OdbcType.Char);
            OdbcParameter PRE_SK1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("PRE_SK1", OdbcType.BigInt);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID_GAMYBA", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PRE_KOD", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);                    
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SAN_KOD", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PRE_SKA", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OBJ_KOD", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRE_KODN", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nl_kod", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ob3_kod", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ob2_kod", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ob4_kod", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pre_sk1", dataGridView_zaliavos.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value);
    try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            //Обрабатываете возможное исключение при открытии
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }        
}
```

now write where ID_gamyba not nulls allow, but my datagridview is fill.[c# error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAtoJ.png)

Comment: add new ODBC command: OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO gamyba1z (ID_GAMYBA, PRE_KOD, PRE_KODN, SAN_KOD, PRE_SKA, NL_KOD, OBJ_KOD, OB3_KOD, OB2_KOD, OB4_KOD, PRE_SK1) VALUES (?, ?, ?, '?', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn);